# 7-1 SCSS pattern in open source project

Tags: css, sass, open-source

Besides the basic structures found on the internet about the 7-1 guides I'm wondering if is there any bigger opensource project that uses that pattern?

If you know such, please put the link to the repo :)

Thank you :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a suitable Stackoverflow question. Please use other channels to promote your open source work.

Comment: @Martin why it's not suitable?